# Corporate reorganization - subsidiary rejoins parent?

Tags: legal-terms, finance

I'm looking for a term to describe when a previously structurally segregated entity is brought back under the parent. I suppose merge isn't wrong here but I wondered if there was something more specific.

Comment: Bonus points for super technical jargon (if it's still accurate)